# Extract "N" Values from an Array

Tags: javascript

**OBJECTIVE**

"Chunky Monkey" Problem: Create a new, multi-dimensional array from a given array ('arr') and number ('size'). The new, multi-dimensional array should create array lengths equal to the 'size' variable.

**EXAMPLE #1**

```
chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
var answer = [];
function chunk(arr,size){
//do something
};

return answer
```

**EXPECTED ANSWER #1**

```
answer = [['a','b'],['c','d']];
```

---

**EXAMPLE #2**

Below is an example when there is an odd number of elements/sizes - In a situation like this, the expected result is to have a "remainder" group.

```
chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 3);
    var answer = [];
    function chunk(arr,size){
    //do something
    };

    return answer
```

**EXPECTED ANSWER #2**

```
answer = [['a','b','c'],['d']];
```

---

---

**MY PSEUDO-CODE / APPROACH**

```
var final = [];
function chunk(arr, size) {
  //extract number of elements from 'arr' = 'size' 
  var extract = function{
    //HELP! [INSERT LOGIC]
  };

  //add extracted elements to 'group' array
  var group = [extract];

  //push 'group' to 'final' array for multidimensional array
  final.push(group);

  //return final'
  return final;
}

chunk(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2);
```

---

**QUESTIONS**

1. I've been looking @ .forEach(), for(in) loops, .slice(), etc. but to no avail. All of my approaches will result in cycling through the array, but not "pairing them".
2. Am I over-complicating things? Is there a more direct approach than my pseudo-code/approach?

Comment: something like `while(x=arr.splice(-2,2).length) array2.push(x);`

Comment: avery time you want to group elements in groups of two? It is always the len of array multiple of `size`?

Comment: @dandavis Am I correct in this analysis: You are using splice() to cycle through an index and then deleting the most recently recorded values?

Comment: @vasilenicusor I am sorry - I don't quite understand your question. With regards to the objective, I am trying to take the original array and break it out into groups equal to the 'size' parameter (e.g size = 3, therefore I should break the original array into new arrays with 3 elements in each)

Comment: This should be a pretty easy thing to do with `Array.Splice`... give me a few minutes to work up a plunker.

Comment: `a=[1,2,3,4,5,6], b=[]; while( (x=a.splice(-2,2)).length) b.push(x); b.reverse();`

Comment: my answer wasn't exactly correct, as I didn't see the additional requirement.  I think it can be done recursively, but other answers are probably more straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive function:

```js
function chunk(arr, size) {
    if(!arr.length) return [];
    return [arr.slice(0, size)].concat(chunk(arr.slice(size), size));
}
```

Or a loop:

```js
function chunk(arr, size) {
    arr = arr.slice();
    var ret = [];
    while(arr.length) ret.push(arr.splice(0, size));
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice` to get the chunks.

```
var chunk = function (arr, size) {
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) {
        res.push(arr.slice(i, i + size));
    }
    return res;
};
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/to7hm7qL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. If the input array is not multiple of `size`, the last group from result will contain the remaining items

```
function chunk(arr, size) {
    var arr_size = arr.length,
        no_groups = arr_size/size,
        i,
        final = [];
    if (no_groups == 0){
        return arr;
    }
    for(i=0;i<no_groups;i++){
        final.push(arr.splice(0, size ));
    }
    return final;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vasilenicusor/22jf8f1o/)